# Summaries of announcement

Tags: sharepoint-designer

On my intranet, developed with SharePoint 2013, I have a WebPart for Announcement.

People who makes Announcement have no text limit for that, but I would like to limit it at 3 lines the text on view.(to see the complete Announcement, people have to click on the hyperlink Title)

I have tried to add a calculated column which return the body column but limited to 200 character.

I didn't found this kind of formula.

Is there another solution for limiting the view to 3 lines instead of the entire Announcement?

Answer (score 0):

you can use JSLink to trim down the body of the announcement. Basically, you will have to create a js file and put your logic there!

Here are couple of links on how to use JSLink to alter the UI of a list

http://www.idubbs.com/blog/2014/js-link-highlighting-a-row-with-csr/

http://jsuhail.blogspot.com/2014/09/client-side-rendering-using-jslink-post_30.html

your logic in the js file will be something similar to that :

```
(function () { 

    // Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it's output render  
    var bodyFieldContext = {}; 
    bodyFieldContext.Templates = {}; 
    bodyFieldContext.Templates.Fields = { 
        // Apply the new rendering for Priority field on List View 
        "bodyField": { "View": bodyFieldTemplate } 
    }; 

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(bodyFieldContext); 

})(); 

// This function provides the rendering logic for list view 
function bodyFieldTemplate(ctx) { 

    var body = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.body];

    var bodyHTML="";
    if (body.toString().length > 250) {
            bodyHTML = body.toString().substring(0,250) + "...";
        }

    return bodyHTML;
}
```

Comment: in your above code example. I guess view is the name of the sps list?

Comment: If yes, where to provide detaila of the specifc column wherein we want to length of trxt.

Comment: got it view here is the default view form. But not sure yet on the column that needs attention.

Comment: I have gone through your code example and thanks for it. I`ve added the code with the required modification to show eclipse (...) for more than 250 characters for Field name: msg under List view name: AllIItems. (List name: msgworld)

        // update by Jason: name of the field: msg and view name : AllItems
        "msg": { "AllItems": bodyFieldTemplate }