# Announcement text msg set length

Tags: web-part

Announcement text msg if more than 5 lines it increases the webpart size to cover the additional lines of text rather showing the eclipse (...) to click if u want to read further.

Alternate, i had set the height of the webpart. But then the scroll bar appears.

I guess it quite a simple javascript or jquery to take care.

Please comment

Comment: I already answered this one before here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/179340/summaries-of-announcement

Comment: @AhmedMahmoud, I have gone through your code example and thanks for it.
I`ve added the code with the required modification to show eclipse (...) for more than 250 characters for Field name: msg under List view name: AllIItems. (List name: msgworld)